# Receive data from gps device

Tags: php, gps, ip, port

I'm newbie to this, so accept my Apology if this is very basic question.

I'm working on a project that was written before, that will receive a string from a gps device and parse the string to track the device.

As much as I found, the gps owner have to set an IP and a port number in device setting that will point to a file for handle incoming string and other stuff.

Now, the server is changed, so the old IP address is not valid, and I have to manage a new IP and port.

Would you please describe me the scenario and how should I do this.
Should I use a firewall rule or do this inside `htaccess` or other stuff?

Assume that the old IP address was `110.102.103.104:3314`, and the new IP is `167.168.169.170`.

I'm confused about port number because the IP address is clear and this is my host IP address.

**More info :**

My host control panel is `directadmin` and programming language is `php`.

***Thanks for your guide***

Comment: Do you still have control of the old IP? If not, you're screwed. What is the OS of the server behind it? You can probably use iptables http://askubuntu.com/questions/513213/ip-port-forward-requests-to-another-server in future use domain names, they're much simpler to move.

Comment: Yes I have. Actually the old server is still running. The site was copied to a new server for a reseller, so the reseller devices have to set new server `IP` and `port`.

Comment: The OS is Linux centOS 6.5

Comment: Then you're in luck. iptables should already be installed by default. See the "getting started" section here to check https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables#head-2760341949881b50946167a95df2945b2f94434a and then just follow the commands in the question I linked before (in the question AND the answer!)